# iOS app custom icons for standard file types like XML

Tags: ios, xml, icons, cfbundledocumenttypes

Is there a way to set up an icon for standard file types like ".xml" when displaying the contents my app's folder in **Files App** or using **UIDocumentPickerViewController**?

It works fine for custom file extensions with UTExportedTypeDeclarations & CFBundleDocumentTypes in info.plist, but for standard file types it just shows a rather unmeaningful default symbol:

[image: file icon]